# I'm trying to access the registry key to be able to add security tab

Tags: windows-registry

I'm trying to get rid of windows sending me messages that word can't display fonts due to storage space, for which i tried to fix this by accessing the security tab in properties for fonts file.
However, for some reason, when trying to get to 'CurrentVersion' after getting to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows, it simply is not there. i got up until Windows. What do i do?

Comment: It should be here. Could you try the following command under CMD to check if the key exist : `REG QUERY HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion`

Comment: I've done that. It seems to show up, how ever it did'nt on registry editor, until i created the key itself

Comment: If the above command correctly show the content of the key, it means that the key exist. If you can't find it with regedit, you can use command line to access it.

Comment: how? my real problem is i'm getting messages from windows saying that word can't display the font b/c it takes up to much space, so i'm trying to solve this through accessing the securitytab, which still isn't showing up, even though the above is showing up in command prompt. maybe you have another idea??

Comment: You should edit your question to add more precision about your real problem

Comment: and now what can i do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Basically, i'm getting these messages saying that Microsoft can't display a said font, due to taking up to much space etc, so i tried the above tactics (trying to access the securitytab to change this) however the securitytab is simply not showing up. When i typed into commandprompt- REG add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer /v Nosecuritytab /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f it showed up that 'access denied'. what can i do for this?

Comment: has anyone got any idea what to do????

Answer (score 0):

This error is often related to security rights on the folder C:\Windows\Fonts.

If you can't access "Security tab" from de GUI, you should try to change it with powershell.

You could try this command (to run under powershell as Administrator) :

```
Get-acl C:\Windows\fonts\arial.ttf | Set-Acl -path c:\windows\fonts\*.*
Get-acl C:\Windows\fonts\arial.ttf | Set-Acl -path c:\windows\fonts
```

Source : https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/there-is-insufficient-memory-or-disk-space-word/18c6b103-1ec6-46be-ba75-3cd0b845b283

Comment: whats 'de GUI' sorry i'm a bit ignorant..

Comment: Graphical User Interface. It's the classical Windows Interface.