# SecurityTab in file explorer

Tags: properties

I've tries both the Registry editor resetting the 'NoSecurityTab' from 0 to 1 and then back, and disabling it in Local Group Policy editor, and both are not working, the security tab is still not showing up.
Note: I've also tried restarting my laptop and it still won't show up.
Any idea's??

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to (a) say what operating system and Home or Pro and (b) a screen shot showing the area where you expect the security tab.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I'm trying to access the registry key to be able to add security tab](https://superuser.com/questions/1726829/im-trying-to-access-the-registry-key-to-be-able-to-add-security-tab)